# In JSTL, how to import a complete external page, along with its images, if the images' path is given with respect to the URL?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am trying to get an external page(http://somewebsite.co/) using JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:import url="http://somewebsite.co/" />
```

but, the images in the source website are stored in a path relative to the website URL:

```
<img alt="" src="images/2f60a6e4a610ec13556cf572e9cc449b_bd6r_cl4e.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" align="right">
```

so, on importing the page, I am not able to view the images because the browser is looking for them relative to my URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/context/my-page.jsp/images/2f60a6e4a610ec13556cf572e9cc449b_bd6r_cl4e.png
```

Is there a way to import the whole page *with* the images directly without editing the HTML of the imported page (the relative link need not necessarily be to image only, it could also be to javascripts, etc..)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with JSTL? Why not just use an iframe?

Comment: I want to edit and display the imported page as an whole page instead of displaying it in an iframe, which makes it look as a page embedded in my page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way of doing this. An approach could be to create a custom jsp tag that does this for you. That way you can process the response before you render it to the client and replace it with fully qualified urls for the images. In general I don't consider this a sensible approach. You can run into many other issues.

You might also want to take a look at frameworks like [ESIGate](http://www.esigate.org/). It allows you to integrate other applications or sites into your existing application.